# How to draw table as vertical using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I need to draw the table in vertical, like all the headings will come as left side as row instead of coming top. Is there any template to draw the table like this ?

Comment: Can you give more details? maybe scratch drawing will help us to get what you need exactly.

Comment: @zur4ik usually heading are coming inside of thead tag and all the headings will be in top of the table. But in my case i need every new row first <td> should be a heading and remaining are should be the value for that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<th>` as first cell:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <td>Row content</td>
        <td>Row content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <td>Row content</td>
        <td>Row content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <td>Row content</td>
        <td>Row content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZQH93/

Comment: It looks good :) But if i want to sort based on the row value means is it possible ??

Comment: @Prabakaran What kind of sort?

Comment: @llya Ascending, descending based on the value